# Jackson annotations not working on a ManyToMany relationship : Infinite loop

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson, annotations

I'm stuck with a problem about converting an Entity to JSON. This Object has a @ManyToMany relationship with an other Entity and no annotation is working ( @JsonManagedReferenced/@JsonBackReference, @JsonIgnore, @JsonIgnoreProperties, @JsonIdentityInfo ). These are working for other relationships in others entities ( but not many to many ).

My first entity :

```
    @Entity
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public class Intervention implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "interventionList")
    private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Intervention() {
        }

// getters and setters 
}
```

My second one :

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @JoinTable(name = "employee_intervention", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "intervention_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Intervention> interventionList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee() {


     }

// getters and setters 
}
```

Here , I am using @JsonIdentityInfo but I tried all of the annotations I mentioned before.

I am getting this error :

```
    Grave:   Generating incomplete JSON
Avertissement:   StandardWrapperValve[jersey-servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.CollectionSerializer.serializeInternal(CollectionSerializer.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:60)

    ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may use `@JsonIgnore` to break the recursion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I tried to use it, but none of the annotations are working, even JsonIgnore on the attribute or/and the getter.

Comment: @MichałZiober all the answers are not solving my issue